# Kafka consumer offset mechanism: How is the topic based storage more better than the ealier zookeeper based storage?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Earlier kafka used to store consumer offsets in zookeeper, but since kafka 0.10 or 0.11 - kafka started to store consumer offsets in an internal topic.

As stated in this [post](https://www.conduktor.io/kafka/kafka-consumer-groups-and-consumer-offsets) -

> Kafka brokers use an internal topic named __consumer_offsets that
> keeps track of what messages a given consumer group last successfully
> processed. As we know, each message in a Kafka topic has a partition
> ID and an offset ID attached to it.

But a topic is not like a DB Table - which can be queried for data based on some input. So I am wondering how this is efficient at all and how exactly does kafka retrieve the offsets for a particular partiton for a particular consumer-group.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Streams or an in-memory hashtable can make compacted topics very much like an KV database store.

The consumer offsets topic is a compacted topic, keyed by group name. When you give a `group.id` in the client, the Controller node and Group Coordinator are easily able to lookup that name from the topic, by key, and return all currently committed offsets for all partitions for the group. Then the consumer looks up the offsets for its assigned partitions from the returned map.

It's not a question of "better". Removing dependencies of Zookeeper was always the goal, and is finally production ready as of Kafka 3.3.1.

Comment: do you mean that `__consumer_offsets` compact topic is continuously processed using kstreams and an in-memory structure with the latest K/V (groupid / partition-offset) info is maintained by kafka broker acting as group coordinator (or actually may by group leader)

Comment: It's not processed using KStreams, but at a high-level, sure.